# Can somebody help me with Azure ML pipeline?

Tags: azure

I am trying to deploy a simple model using azure pipeline but unable to do so. Can somebody tell me a good resource to follow. 
P.S. I tried the offical docs but got stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use this link: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/ml-net-model-lifecycle-with-azure-devops-ci-cd-pipelines/

The author describes ML model lifecycle via Azure DevOps